# How to add paginator controls to the view?

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I want to create paginator on my news feed.

I had developed controller and it is working fine now. Links like:

```
example.com/news/page-1
...
example.com/news/page-10
etc
```

are working fine.

Now I need to add paginator controlls in the view file. I found this in docs.

In [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#rendering-pages-with-view-scripts) part of docs there is an example, where `paginatorControls` is rendered like this:

```
echo $this->paginationControl(
    $this->paginator,
    'Sliding',
    'my_pagination_control', 
    array('route' => 'application/paginator')
);
```

`my_pagination_control` is partial, as I assumed. Maybe, I am blind, but I can't find on the docs where I have to define this partial? Possibly in config file. But how?

Also, I don't understand how 2nd option (parameter — `Sliding`) of `paginationControl` function will interract with partial. Can you clarify this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my_pagination_control is partial, as I assumed. Maybe, I am blind, but I can't find on the docs where I have to define this partial? Possibly in config file. But how?

As you've identified, you map it in your module config just like you would for any other partial, for example ...

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'my_pagination_control' => __DIR__ . '/../view/paginator/control.phtml',
    ),
),
```

> Also, I don't understand how 2nd option (parameter — Sliding) of paginationControl function will interract with partial. Can you clarify this, please?

The parameter doesn't interact with the partial, it's used to get the correct pages from the paginator for that particular scrolling style.  It's up to you to create appropriate partials for each of the different scrolling styles you want to use, map them as above, and then use them as needed.

Comment: Is it possible to set 1 pagination partial and use it everywhere? In news module news list, in categories list, in users list etc, using only one partial. I don't need partial for each controls, right? Can I use only one?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it's possible yes, you'd usually do that by having the url view helper calls in your paginator partial re-use matched route params (fourth parameter of url view helper), see -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html#reusing-matched-parameters

Comment: Btw, your answer helped me, I have working controls now: [click me](http://i.gyazo.com/0bfe3248a216282210d008628807ca84.png) (image 8,87 kb). But I tried `Jumping` or `Sliding` as 2nd parameter and I got 1 result. Why? Is there a scrolling style, where only 3-5 pages will be shown and others wouln't be shown? Like if I am on 6 page this shown: `first < 4 5 6 7 8 > last`, if on 20 this will be shown: `first < 18 19 20 21 22 > last`. Is it possible? Or it is better to use suggested? Or might be I had tried this on small amount of pages and I would see effect on more pages? I tried 7-10.

Comment: Is current page number send to view and can be accessed by `$this` in view file? I want to add current page number, if it is not first page, but I don't know how.

Comment: Also, is there a way to get total pages of paginator in view? I understand, that I can send both this values (total pages and current page to view from controller, but I don't want overload it). [This](https://www.google.ru/search?q=how+to+get+total+pages+of+paginator+in+view&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=-BKLU4SREO6A4ASYm4CQCA#channel=fflb&newwindow=1&q=how+to+get+total+pages+of+paginator+in+view+zf2&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official) (google search link) doesn't help :)

Comment: @SharikovVladislav yes, you need more pages to see the effect with the `sliding` scroll style. As for current page number, the paginator instance which you iterate over has a `getCurrentPageNumber()` method.

Comment: Where exactly it is better to store `*.phtml` partial of pagination controls if I want to use it in different modules? It is not good to manually add `phtml` file and row to config to each module, isn't it? It is good to do it in `Application` module? Will application partials will be available in other modules?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav yes, put the partials in any module that you always load, and yes view templates are available to all modules no matter which module supplied them (provided the module's loaded of course)